# How does the Craft CMS built-in web server works?

Tags: php, server, cli

I just found this while using `./craft help` in the Craft CMS command line utilities:

```
- serve                                      Runs the PHP built-in web server.
    serve/index (default)                    Runs PHP built-in web server.
```

- How to use this built-in web server?
- How can I edit these web server
  settings?
- Can i use multiple of these web server at once?

At this time of writing, I didn't find any documentation about that.

I'm using the latest version of Craft CMS (Craft Pro 3.3.17) under Mac OS (10.14.6).

Answer (score 3):

This just launches PHP's built in web server, documentation for it can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

You can use `php -s localhost:8000` instead

You can see available settings by running `php -s`

Yes you can run multiple versions on different ports

Hope this helps!